# PUGXMultiUserBundle UserManager fails to create user fixture

Tags: symfony, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm on Symfony 2.8.2. I installed:

```
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
```

I configured two types of users, just like in the [documentation](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), except for the `targetClass` argument in `UniqueEntity` annotation, which seems not to be accepted.

Now I'm trying to load fixtures, like this:

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\Portal\AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use CompanyName\Common\CommonBundle\Entity\AdminUser;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadUsers extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $discriminator = $this->container->get('pugx_user.manager.user_discriminator');
        $discriminator->setClass('CompanyName\Common\CommonBundle\Entity\AdminUser');

        $userManager = $this->container->get('pugx_user_manager');

        $user = new $userManager->createUser();

        $user->setUsername("admin");
        $user->setPlainPassword("test");
        $user->setEmail('email@example.com');
        $user->setFirstName('John');
        $user->setSurname('Smith');
        $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN'));
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


}
```

But when I `doctrine:fixtures:load`, I get:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Notice: Undefined property: PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::$createUser
```

Can you explain that to me? I checked UserManager class, it has createUser function.

Comment: OK, I don't know how that **new** got in there before $userManager->createUser(), but that was the problem.